# "... are likely to arrive like earthquakes, so much has that orientation produced ..."

Tags: grammar

> Even relatively fractional adjustments to the West's basic orientation toward business and financial capitalism are likely to arrive like earthquakes, ***so much*** has that orientation produced the culture's collective sense of what is thinkable and what is not.

In this sentence, what I can see between two clauses is just "so much", and in the second clause it seems like the subject and the verb are inverted ("that orientation has produced" > "has that orientation produced").

Can *so much* do this alone? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Less cluttered examples, putting the reason clause first, are << So far ahead are Arsenal that no other team has a chance of catching them. >>  And << So many goals have City scored that no other team will achieve a higher tally. >> The 'that' would be dropped if the clause order were adjusted to mirror OP's example. Another example, << No one will pass, so high is the pass mark. >> In many cases,  a more natural, less rarefied variant is possible uninverting the reason clause: << No one will pass,[/because] the pass mark is so high. >> // << The pass mark is so high that no one will pass. >>

Comment: Is it a typo that was supposed to be: “***in so much as** that orientation*...”?